# What does "apachectl" stand for? Why isn't it just "apache"?

Tags: linux, apache

This should be easy, just curious.  I know "httpd" is the HTTP daemon, just curious what the relationship is between "httpd" and "apachectl."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's short for apache control(ler?).  It tells apache what to do, but it isn't the service itself.

Answer (score 13):

`httpd` is the practical daemon. It's the part that really does the job. `apachectl` is how you can control this daemon, and do operations on it. It's merely a control interface, not the real program itself.

From the manpage :

> apache2ctl is a front end to the Apache HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) server.  It is designed to help the administrator control the functioning of the Apache apache2 daemon.

(I have apache2 on my machine but it's the same thing)

Answer (score 6):

[apachectl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/programs/apachectl.html) - Apache HTTP server **control** interface

Looks like it is just an old naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

The program `apachectl` helps control the Apache HTTPD daemon.

Answer (score 2):

The server binary itself is called `httpd` in the upstream distribution, but `apache2` in others such as the debian package.

`apachectl` or `apache2ctl` (ctl stands for **c**on**t**ro**l**) is a shell script that allows starting/stopping/etc. the bunch of `httpd` or `apache2` processes.